# pytorch summary RuntimeError, expected channels mismatch

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am new to AI, when i try to get the summary info from my network, i got RuntimeError:
[image: this]
what parameter should i pass, according to the error? thanks.

Comment: please do not post screen shots of errors/logs: search engines cannot "read" them. Instead, copy-paste your code and error log.

Answer (score 0):

Your first layer expects 3 channels input (in images this usually means a color image with Red, Green and Blue channels), but your input seems to have only one channel (in images this usually means your input image is a grey-scale image and not a color image).